# You clicked "no action needed" which allowed a spammer to escape unnoticed

Tags: support

I just went to the review queue and received this notice:

> You clicked "no action needed" on https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7161146 which allowed a spammer to escape unnoticed for much longer than they should have.
>
> Come back in 7 days to continue reviewing.

I remember the question, but not the particular answer. When I reviewed the answer, it was not an audit because there was no warning that I failed an audit. If I check the review, I cannot see the answer. I just get the unhelpful "answer not found":

> Answer
>
> ---
>
> *answer not found*

Would someone with enough reputation to view the deleted answer post a copy of it so that I can look it over to see what I missed?

Comment: It looks like you also missed two grammar errors and a spelling mistake. Even if I missed the fairly obvious self-promotional link to the author's website, I would have at least fixed those issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [image]

(Not C&P on purpose.)

Comment: This seems like an interesting case - while the link to their web design site is obviously self-promotion that's unrelated to the question, the suggestion of using CCleaner to remove the cache is actually a valid possible answer to the question. What's the policy on part-spam posts that nonetheless do make an attempt to answer?

Comment: They've been spamming SO for quite a while; once you hang out in the Low-Quality Review queue long enough, you're bound to see this one pop up again

Comment: So what should one do in this case? The answer isn't great, but I think it addresses the question: try CCleaner (I've heard of it, and it looks like the proper link). However, the link back to some random website is spammy.

Comment: @cpburnz You should have done *something*.  Clearly this is not just an appropriate post.  Whether you flagged it as spam, or did something else to indicate that there is at least something wrong with it would have been good enough.

Comment: @sphanley: This is clearly not an answer. It consists entirely of an off-site link to a third-party product and another self-promoting off-site link. This type of answer is totally unacceptable here, because there is no solution *here* to the problem **and** because if the external link(s) are unavailable there is zero meaningful content. This should have been a lightning-fast close vote, and the absolute wrong response to it was "no action needed". I'm not sure I would have flagged it as spam, because I'm not sure it meets those guidelines, though; it's definitely close-worthy.

Comment: @KenWhite Clearly I should have done something. Since this was under the *First Posts* queue where there are no close vote options, how should I flag future answers if I'm not sure whether they are spam? Not an answer? Very low quality? Or flag as spam if I have a slight suspicion?

Comment: @cpburnz: If you think there might be something, but are not sure, try digging for corroborative data: Visit the links, user-profile and the question-page. That should give you all the info you need to decide how to proceed, even if at the end it's "skip, still not sure".

Comment: @cpburnz: If you have no close option available, flag it as VLQ unless you're sure it meets the somewhat narrow guidelines for spam. Spam flags have somewhat severe ramifications for the user (loss of reputation, account suspension or even deletion, and even IP banning in some cases), so a *slight suspicion* should not get a spam flag. I disagree with Deduplicator about visiting the links; whether they're valid or not means nothing in this context. If the links are to a stable site like Microsoft MSDN or Apple dev support, they're fine. If they're some third-party tool or a personal site, not.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @KenWhite: Well, often just looking at the link gives enough info, other times, following it makes the decision easy. And anyway, it's just for getting evidence, not testing for link-rot.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I consider every link within context. An answer that says "You can use Somefunction to do this thing. It does this. More details about use here. You can find documentation at *this link*", where the link is used appropriately to provide additional details or sample code at a site which can be considered relatively stable is fine. The type of links posted in the code in question here are never appropriate, particularly when used as they were here. There is no content in the question here that provides a solution whatsoever, and thus no future value if the links disappear.